# Install Ubuntu x64 over x32 on a multi-boot system

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit

Can I do a fresh install of Ubuntu x64 (I currently have Ubuntu x32 bit installed) on a multi-boot system (Win XP/7/8)? Will I run to any problems as far as booting up to my other O/S'es?

Comment: And you want to keep the 32-bit version!? Why would you want that?

Comment: No I don't want to keep the 32-bit version. I want to replace it with 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the x64 version and boot it off a USB. Then install it on the existing partition. No, it will not affect your Windows OS.